# What to do about bad photo on issued US passport

Tags: passports

When I applied for my US passport, I had my photo taken at the US Post Office.  Unfortunately their photo came out very washed out and overexposed. You can see my face but it's not great.  Despite this, my passport was issued using the photo.

I have used the passport on a few trips so far to "easy" countries (Europe, Canada...) without problem.  My concern is that if I visit a country that's less accustomed to waving Americans through their doors, I might run into problems.  Should I be concerned, and if so what can I do about getting the photo replaced?

Comment: Have you tried the obvious of getting your passport renewed?  And when you talk about *country that's less accustomed to waiving Americans through their doors*, which ones do you mean? North Korea? Iran?

Comment: Wasn't aware renewal accepted a new picture, I see now that it does.  As far as countries, for example the procedure to get into Italy was very fast with minimal passport examination.  I imagine this is because they receive a flood of American tourists all summer. My concern was that other countries (to name one at random, Vietnam) might have more extensive review in which the picture would be a problem.

Comment: Usually you will submit a picture to receive a visa in which you will have a picture again.

Comment: Here's a link that explicitly says you can't do this without replacing your passport. http://traveltips.usatoday.com/new-picture-passport-1699.html

Comment: Renewing your passport is the same effectively as replacing for this scenario.

Comment: @Karlson: try the United Kingdom. On a US passport, I've never had anyone say anything more than "Welcome" in at least five entries to three different Schengen countries, but in the UK I am always treated with suspicion.

Comment: @Max I think OPs issue is border control and I don't think that in the UK you will be asked to present your passport on every corner.  But if you're treated with suspicion it might be just you... :-)

Comment: @Karlson: I meant at border controls.

Comment: @Max Still might be just you...

Answer (score 1):

Per Karlson, it appears that a simple renewal will take care of this.  I just have to decide when I want to pay the $110 to make the renewal early.  Maybe before my next trip into the unknown.